# How to post hidden inputs in example below

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table below which contains Question numbers, replies and answers. Lets say the table looks like this below:

```
QuestionNo   Reply         Answer

1            Single        A D
2            Multiple      B E F
3            Multiple      C
4            Single        D H
```

What I want to do is $_POST these values so then I can insert them in the database.

I want to insert each answer to their relevant question so I created a for loop. But my question is that how do I write the switch statement so that it posts the correct answers for each question?

Below is the for loop and the mysqli code which will insert the answer values, I just need help writing the switch statement:

```
    $i = 0;
    $c = count($_POST['gridValues']);  //count each table row

    for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

   //switch statement for each answer post goes here

    }

   $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (Answer) 
    VALUES (?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  

    $insertanswer->bind_param("s", $_POST[''][$i]);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();

    }
```

Each answer has its own name attribute, there are 30 different answers and below is example of how it can be posted:

```
$_POST['answerAvalue']  //Answer A
$_POST['answerBvalue']  //Answer B
$_POST['answerCvalue']  //Answer C
$_POST['answerDvalue']  //Answer D

....

$_POST['answerTruevalue']  //Answer True
$_POST['answerFalsevalue'] //Answer False
$_POST['answerYesvalue']   //Answer Yes
$_POST['answerNovalue']    //Answer No
```

Answer (score 1):

Crazy question, but I have one recommendation for you, change this:

```
switch ($_POST['reply'][$i]){ 

case "single": 
$selected_reply = "Single"; 
break; 

case "multiple": 
$selected_reply = "Multiple"; 
break; 

default: 
$selected_reply = ""; 
break; 

}
```

On this:

```
$selected_reply = "";
if (isset($_POST['reply'][$i])) {
    $selected_reply = ucfirst($_POST['reply'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: From his example there are concrete values in the POST data. And we must validate only if this data is exists.

Comment: I will change my question and try make it easier to understand